# Scoping rules in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Even though I have used Clojure, I hadn't looked at the scoping rules in detail. I am getting more confused as I read the documentations.
I made a small test to try out the scoping resolutions and am apalled at the complexity. Could somebody explain the intent and various rules that Clojure uses?

```
(def x 1)

(defn dummy-fn2[]
    (+ x 1))        

(defn dummy-fn[]
    (println "entering function: " x)
      (let [x 100]
         (println "after let: " x)
         (let [x (dummy-fn2)]
            (println "after let and dummy2: " x)
            (binding [x 100]
             (println "after binding: " x)
             (let [x (dummy-fn2)]
               (println "after binding and dummy2: " x))))))

1:2 foo=> (dummy-fn)
entering function:  1
after let:  100
after let and dummy2:  2
after binding:  2
after binding and dummy2:  101
nil
```

Comment: In order to avoid repeating the documentation, perhaps you could describe what you expect and why it's different from what actually happens.

Answer (score 25):

`let` shadows the toplevel Var `x` with a local `x`.  `let` does not create a Var or affect the toplevel Var; it binds some symbol such that local references to that symbol will be replaced with the `let`-bound value.  `let` has lexical scope, so its bindings are only visible within the `let` form itself (not in functions called from within the `let`).

`binding` temporarily (thread-locally) changes the value of the toplevel Var `x`, that's all it does.  If a `let` binding is in place, `binding` doesn't see it when deciding which value to change (and `let`'s bindings are not vars and are not alterable, so that' a good thing or it'd give you an error).  And `binding` won't mask `let`.  `binding` has dynamic scope, so its affects on toplevel Vars are visible within the `binding` form and in any function that is called from within the `binding` form.

Accessing the value of plain old `x` will give you whatever is at the top of the stack of bindings, either the most nested `let`-bound value of `x` (or the function paramater called `x`, or some value `x` is replaced with if you use your own macro, or other possibilities.), and only uses the current value of the toplevel Var `x` by default if there is no other binding in place.

Even if the toplevel Var `x` is masked by a `let`-bound `x`, you can always access the toplevel Var via `@#'x`.  Try this version, maybe it'll make more sense:

```
(def x 1)

(defn dummy-fn2[]
  (println "x from dummy-fn2:" x)
  (+ x 1))  

(defn dummy-fn[]
  (println "entering function:" x)
  (println "var x:" @#'x)
  (dummy-fn2)
  (println "---")
  (let [x 100]
    (println "after let:" x)
    (println "var x:" @#'x)
    (dummy-fn2)
    (println "---")
    (let [x (dummy-fn2)]
      (println "after let and dummy-fn2:" x)
      (println "var x:" @#'x)
      (dummy-fn2)
      (println "---")
      (binding [x 888]
        (println "after binding:" x)
        (println "var x:" @#'x)
        (dummy-fn2)
        (println "---")
        (let [x (dummy-fn2)]
          (println "after binding and dummy2:" x)
          (println "var x:" @#'x)
          (dummy-fn2)
          (println "---"))))))
```

Gives:

```
entering function: 1
var x: 1
x from dummy-fn2: 1
---
after let: 100
var x: 1
x from dummy-fn2: 1
---
x from dummy-fn2: 1
after let and dummy-fn2: 2
var x: 1
x from dummy-fn2: 1
---
after binding: 2
var x: 888
x from dummy-fn2: 888
---
x from dummy-fn2: 888
after binding and dummy2: 889
var x: 888
x from dummy-fn2: 888
---
```

Comment: I'm getting `IllegalStateException Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var` when I run this code.  It's resolved by either replacing the `binding` form with `let` or using `(def ^:dynamic x 1)`

Answer (score 14):

Clojure uses both **lexical scope** `let` for symbols and **dynamic scope** `binding` for vars 
check out clojure's [vars](http://clojure.org/vars) documentation.

- *"entering function"*: doing fine so far! the symbol x resolves to the var and this is grabbing the "root binding" of the var x.
- *"after let"*: a local binding covered up the var, the symbol x is now 100 not a var.
- *"after let and dummy2"*: the x in dummy-fn2 refers to the var x, so it uses the root binding of x and returned one more than that (+ 1 1)
- *"after binding"*: tricky one! binding dynamically replaced the root binding of the var named x (which was 1) with 100, but the local symbol x is not the var anymore so you get the local binding.
- *"after binding and dummy2"*: the binding replaced the root value of the var x with 100 and this returned one more than that (+ 100 1)

Comment: it looks like binding replaces "the var with name x", not "the var that the symbol x resolves to" is this correct?

Comment: What does "the var with name x" mean?

Comment: I mean, I think "the var that symbol x resolves to" and "the var with name x" are essentially the same thing; I don't see any distinction.

Comment: Oops, now I see what you're referring too. Carper's right, there isn't a distinction. `let` shadows the Var with a local, `binding` shadows the value of Var `x` with a new value. There is only ever one Var.

Comment: "the var that symbol x resolves to" and "the var with name x"  differ when x currently resolves to something that is not a var. like the number 2